# How to handle `window.close` after being opened by the `webView.uiDelegate`?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, popup, wkwebview

I'm developing a WKWebView-App for iOS that increases the functionality of an existing website but I can't change the source code of this website.

When the user clicks on some buttons, they trigger the `window.open`.
I've successfully overwritten the delegate function accordingly:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    let popups = getJSfromURL(url: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "popups", ofType: "js")!)
    contentController.addUserScript(popups)

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.userContentController = contentController

    let popupView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    popupView.load(navigationAction.request)
    view = popupView
    return nil
}
```

In this popup, there is a button which calls a `this.close()` but the browser complains, that this can't be closed because it wasn't opened by javascript.

Another button wants to set some parameters which have been set by the user but the browser complains, that the `opener`-parameter is `nil`.

Could I use an injected javascript in some way to set the opener prior opening the popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kind of fixed this problem by **setting the source of the presented website** to the src of the popup.

Now the popup is presented in the same context and can post back the information given without a problem.

**For example:**

The button `New`that triggers the popup `../training/NewTraining.aspx` calls the javascript-function `showNew()`.

Now I simply added this function to my injected javascript so it will be executed:

```
function showNeu() {
    parent.parent.frames[1].location.href='../training/TrainingNeu.aspx';
}
```

As well I altered the javascript for the button `Abort` that closes the popup:

```
var btnAbort = document.getElementById('ASPxRoundPanel3_btnAbort');
if (btnAbort) {
    btnAbort.onclick = function () {parent.window.location = "/MainPage.aspx";};
}
```